# Which knitr option controls typeset vs. code-like output from knitr (LaTeX)

Tags: r, latex, knitr, listings

What controls the difference between these two outputs?

To produce the desired R-like output in the first image, I had to add `%>% print()`

[image: desired LaTeX output from knitr]

The following seems to have become the default format (presumably due to my inadvertent setting of a knitr option):

[image: undesirable LaTeX output from knitr]

Comment: Depends on your output format. For HTML, look at [the docs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#data-frame-printing) and try adjusting the `df_print` option

Answer (score 3):

There's a generic function called `knit_print` with methods for various classes; run `methods("knit_print")` to see what they are with the packages you have loaded.  If your final object (which probably has classes `"tbl_df"`, `"tbl"`, and `"data.frame"`) has a class for which there's a `knit_print` method, that's what it will use.  Running `example(knit_print)` will create a `data.frame` method.

From the other answer, it appears that it was the `printr` package which added a `knit_print.data.frame` method.  To work around this, you can use the `render` chunk option, e.g.

````
```{r}
library(printr)
head(mtcars)
```

```{r render = print}
head(mtcars)
```
````

which yields this output:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the syntax to set this as an option at the beginning of the file? Where should it go: in ```opts_chunk$set```, or ```opts_knit$set```, or somewhere else? Finally, why isn't it ```render = "print"``` (like ```fig.show = "hold"```)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting it routinely for the whole file.  That will cause things like `plotly` images and other fancy HTML output to fail to print properly.  But if you don't mind losing those, use `knitr::opts_chunk$set(render = print)`.  The `render` option is supposed to be the function to do the rendering.  I don't know if using its name in quotes would work.

Comment: Does your comment apply to LaTeX as well?

Comment: Yes, plotly images can be displayed in LaTeX by taking a screenshot.  That won't happen with `print`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading `vignette('knit_print', package = 'knitr')` I discovered that in my case the cause was that I had blindly added `library(printr)` in the preamble of my Rnw file, which produced formatted output (as in my second inserted image). When I commented out that line, the output was as you would see it in interacting with R in the console (as in the first image).

Comment: That package adds `knit_print` methods to 8 classes:  https://github.com/yihui/printr/blob/03af6da72568d846909700d42462bdd8987129f2/NAMESPACE#L3-L10, including `"data.frame"`.

Comment: There's a workaround for it, which I've added to my answer.